# Protagonist is way too overpowered

Tags: conflict

In my story I've created a main protagonist called "The Paradox". He is connected via quantum entanglement to a space-time matrix which connects him to the minds and bodies of pretty much every superhero  you can think of, allowing him to access the abilities of said superheroes. 
I have no idea how to create a conflict with this character without taking his abilities away from him.

Example: when exposed to kryptonite he loses all abilities related to Superman but he can still use the powers of Hulk to gain super strength and beat the antagonist to bloody pulp.

**How do I get around the issue without 'de-supering" my protagonist**

Comment: This sounds like a narrative problem not a worldbuilding one.

Comment: Oh did I post in the wrong forum

Comment: "How do I create conflict for my character?" isn't about creating a fictional world. Not to be a pedant but we are a question and answer site and not a forum. You could try [writing.se] but **make sure you read their rules about what is and is not an appropriate question before posting there.**

Comment: If you want to know more about what is appropriate for this site you can take the [tour] and visit the [help].

Comment: You just ultra-munchkined your charecter. You can't have it all, short of giving him an opponent with roughly the same powers. And a beard I suppose.

Comment: He still can't be in two places at once, I guess. And he still may have vulnerable friends.

Comment: (1) You created a god, what were you expecting?  (2) No story feels real unless the characters have relatable limitations and weaknesses.  Even Superman's Kryponite is relatable... among other things, it can be considered a metaphor for human temptation (I just want a piece of my home...  or a boat with too much debt... or a drug that disables me... or a relationship that's abusive... is that too much to ask?)  Do you believe Superman was less super because he had a weakness?  Curious.

Comment: He is only "The Paradox" when he is asleep and dreaming. At other times, he is called Joe and works in a comic book store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to find a source of conflict where his physical powers are useless, or at least not directly applicable.

**Option 1: Moral Conflict**
Yes, he can do anything and is super-powered, but what gives him the right to be judge over all humanity? If he doesn't have super-super powers he could be challenged by saving someone he knows vs saving a crowd of other people, or killing the villain will result in deaths of innocents. If he does have super-super powers, then make him have personal doubts about what he is doing. For a bit of this, watch the short film "[the flying man](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gj1MqHgFnmE)"

**Option 2: Human error**
Does he suffer from inflated ego and pride leading him to make errors of judgement? Everyone makes mistakes, even a super-super-super hero. Maybe the first time he walks into a hostage situation he isn't cautious enough and the bad guys kill everyone before he makes it through the door (they hear him coming). Maybe he just makes a mistake with his powers and knocks down an apartment building, killing those inside.

**Option 3: Reluctant hero** Could he actually want to be a farmer but is pursued by a government wanting to study him? Or maybe he's just lazy and wants to work a 9-5 job like everyone else. Having super-powers doesn't make you a hero by default.